# How to initialize fields with size others fields in entity JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, initialization

I have a example JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_group")
public class Group
{
  ...

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "tb_group_user",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
   private List<User> users;

   private Integer userSize;
   ...
}
```

My question is, how can i initialize userSize field, with the size value of users field,that is a Lazy Load field?

I know its a dumb question, but i can't find a good strategy to solve this problem.

I tried this solution, but haven't succeed:

`private Integer userSize = users.size();`

I'm confused with this problem. Can you help me with an example?

**EDIT:**

I tried solution `@Formula("select count(gu.fk_user_id) from tb_group_user gu where gu.fk_group_id = id")` suggested by [Ady Junior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278773/ady-junior), but i receive this exceptions, when i try get groups:

```
ERROR   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
select count(gu.fk_user_id) from tb_group_user gu where gu.fk_group_id = group

ERROR   br.com.loopec.loopkey.server.controller.ExceptionsHandler   
Unhandled Exception: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

**EDIT 2:**

I got it solved the problem. [Ady Junior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278773/ady-junior) give me a good solution, and the error was due to my stupidity. Inside `@Formule("select count(gu.fk_user_id) from tb_group_user gu where gu.fk_group_id = id")` i forgot putied parentheses '(' ')' between query.

The correct solution for my problem this:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "tb_group")
 public class Group
 {
   ...

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "tb_group_user",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
   private List<User> users;
   @Formula("(select count(gu.fk_user_id) from tb_group_user gu where gu.fk_group_id = id)")
   private Integer userSize;
   ...
}
```

Thanks [Ady Junior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278773/ady-junior) and Thanks [Christian Beikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412446/christian-beikov)

Comment: Try it ---> @Formula("select count(gu.fk_user_id) from tb_group_user gu where gu.fk_group_id = id")
private Integer userSize;      // Tell me if it will work

Comment: Did you tried to use above solution?

Comment: I found my error. Thanks Ady, and Vila Nova is a Great Team hahahaha :)

Comment: Very good @devsaleh. Man, now I'm your fan, for talking about VILA (kkkk). Thanks.
If I post the answer do you mark it as correct?

Comment: Of course, Ady!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

devsaleh, try use @Formula to write a count query.

There are many features about this annotation. For instance, in this awesome post written by Vlad Mihalcea: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-calculated-properties-with-jpa-and-hibernate-formula-annotation/

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "tb_group")
 public class Group
 {
   ...

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "tb_group_user",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
   private List<User> users;
   @Formula("(select count(gu.fk_user_id) from tb_group_user gu where gu.fk_group_id = id)")
   private Integer userSize;
   ...
}
```

@devsaleh, Thank you very much!

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You could use extra-lazy collections with `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)` but I wouldn't recommend that: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-extra-lazy-collections/

The approach Ady Junior proposed i.e. to use `@Formula("select count(gu.fk_user_id) from tb_group_user gu where gu.fk_group_id = id")` is a way you could go, but probably it's better to use a DTO query and determine the size in the query you use to load the data. Something like this

`entityManager.createQuery("SELECT g.name, SIZE(g.users) FROM Group g")`

Comment: Christian Beikov thanks for the answer. Could you give me an example of what it would look like in the group entity? A code example.